# Background image for jQuery overlay does not display, but works fine (IE10/Chrome)

Tags: jquery, html, css, overlay, background-image

I'm using the example [here](http://jquerytools.github.com/demos/overlay/apple.html) as a starting point. I have a website, and I wanted to add overlay functionality. I have copied the code over from the link above. The overlay works as expected, but I do not see the close button.

I am able to click on it, and click outside the overlay to dismiss it, in both Chrome and IE10. The x mark is however, not displayed. I tried changing the z-index to no avail. The close class is supposed to be generated automatically. All other css properties I messed with, the image responded. Except displaying the actual image. I thought it was the path, so I moved the image to the root folder, still nothing.

```
.apple_overlay .close {
background-image:url(close.png);
background-color:darkgreen;
position:absolute; right:5px; top:5px;
cursor:pointer;
height:35px;
width:35px;
```

}

What am I missing here? Thanks for looking.

Comment: Could You specify some more details (js, html)? You could share Your example on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Are you sure the image is where it is supposed to be ?

If you use the chrome dev tools (pressing F12) is there any errors, what is the computed value of the element ?

Comment: Thank you so much, Lostdreamer, I was able to find the error using F12 on Chrome. It was looking for the image in the wrong place :)